# Ticket Notification using Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

We are planning to develop a Ticketing Application and would like to use Kafka as a way to send notifications.
The major requirement is:
1. Send an email in 2hrs for ticket 1
2. Send an email in 30min for ticket 2
This would be the kind of information that we have. Is it possible to execute these messages say after 2hrs they were published?

The use case is:
1. A ticket in Priority 0 is in NEW status. Send an alert if the ticket is in NEW status even after 30min of ticket created time. Now, suppose the status has changed, then we need to cancel the email that was scheduled earlier and will now have another message to be sent.

Our Application is in C#

Comment: Sounds possible. Lock into Kafka's Streams API and punctuations.

Comment: I would suggest to use Apache Camel to bind "e-mail-ing" with data source and perhaps with Kafka.
But I do not clearly see what for are you using Kafka.
Where are located "tickets"? Are they in DB?

Comment: Our aim is to create a separate system for notification so that it can be used for other applications as well. The ticketing system is a different system and we are planning to publish into kafka and based on a time at which it has to be executed, and subscribe from kafka after the processing/delay. Tickets are in an oracle database.